# test not running on karma/jasmine/require.js 'There is no timestamp for *lib*!' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

I change the code, extend some functionality and add new unittest for that. Now, when I run my unit tests with **karma** (test framework -  **jasmine**), it throw me an error

```
'There is no timestamp for /libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js!'
Uncaught Error: Script error for: angular-bootstrap
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js?1379984163000:138
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the karma config file?

Comment: update the question's body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my mistake completely. when using `karma-requirejs` you have `main-test.js` file where configure how to `require.js` get the files. I add reference to angular-bootstrap with mistake, that's why `require.js` couldn't find this file and throwing this mistake. *So in my case this error means wrong file name provided.*

Comment: Is it possible for you to show where the mistake was in your `main-test.js` file?

Comment: It's a bit hard to remember for sure, because It was like 4 month ago, but I think it was a typo or the wrong order of dependencies.

Comment: just a heads up, changing the values in test-main and karma.conf doesn't go into effect until you restart the testing process in the terminal. So save the files and do "karma start" after

Comment: @Millenjo you only have to restart the runner if you make an update to karma.conf, the runner updates when you make a change to main-test.

Comment: Karma allows to exclude dirs from autoloading ( __e.g karma.conf.js -> files__ section), letting __requirejs__ (only if _'requirejs'_ is loaded in __e.g karma.conf.js -> frameworks__ section but also _'karma-requirejs'_ in  _e.g karma.conf.js -> plugins__) doing the job. In my case, had to add those imports in **shim** section. e.g '<import-alias>': {deps: ['<package-alias>']}

Answer (score 1):

It can be because it cannot access your source file. You should configure karma to serve scripts where require will look for them.
For example have the config in the karma conf

```
files:[{pattern: 'node_modules/**/*.js', included:false}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, the OP already solved his problem by now, but I'll add my two cents:

From the error message (end of the first error line) we can conclude that you were including a `paths` (or `deps`) file in `main-test.js` with the `.js` extension.
In RequireJS, you need to call the file names *without* the extension, so your `paths` (or `deps`) would look more or less like this:

```js
paths: {
    'ui-bootstrap': 'libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls' // <- without the extension
}
```