# Configure Karma-dojo to use local repository of dojo

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to set up a local testing environment for my Dojo project. I've decided on Karma as the test runner and Jasmine as the suite. I've found a few example karma.config files on how to set it up and that works fine.
But when I try to set up the dojo.config in main test file to point to a local version of dojo it just breaks.
This works:

```
var dojoConfig = {
packages: [
    {
        name: 'dojo',
        location: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo'
    }, {
        name: 'dojox',
        location: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox'
    }, {
        name: 'dijit',
        location: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit'
    }
],
async: true
```

};

But as soon as I do something like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
packages: [
    {
        name: 'dojo',
        location: 'base/lib/dojo'
    }, {
        name: 'dojox',
        location: 'base/lib/dojox'
    }, {
        name: 'dijit',
        location: 'base/lib/dijit'
    }
],
async: true
```

};

This is the error log:

```
ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/lib/dojo/domReady.js!'
ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/lib/dojo/_base/array.js!'
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/lib/dojo/domReady.js
```

Then it runs through and outputs the same for all dojo modules.

Comment: How does it break? What error message are you receiving? We need information like that to be able to help you

Comment: Thanks StormeHawke. I've added the error log. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Can you share your karma.conf.js?

Comment: You need to have `lib/dojo/*.js` in `files`. It looks like Karma does serve these files.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd error... I can't give you much more than a Google search (You did google your error right?), but have you seen these questions?

[test not running on karma/jasmine/require.js 'There is no timestamp for *lib*!' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016478/test-not-running-on-karma-jasmine-require-js-there-is-no-timestamp-for-lib)

[karma error 'There is no timestamp for'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733090/karma-error-there-is-no-timestamp-for)